# Alamofire has been installed, but still could not be imported in Xcode8?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode8

I have installed alamofire in Xcode 8.1 using pod file. alamofire folder has been created with files. But still could not import alamofire.it is giving me an error no such module exists when I am trying to install alamofire.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUOoI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUOoI.png)

Comment: The picture has something wrong. If you use pod file, the inspector will have 2 components: your project and pod project.

Comment: why doesn't it has pod project. kindly help

Comment: use projectname.xcworkspace to open. dont use .xcodeproj

Comment: I did but still it hasn't changed anything

Comment: look at the updated screenshot

Comment: @vipulbansal image is not still updated

Comment: It seem to be ok. If error still showed, try to clean your project.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It has successfully built. I am very new to iOS. I am an android developer as yet.